# Waterline ORM (sails.js) "where or" in query

Tags: javascript, orm, sails.js, waterline

I would like to know how to add "OR" condition in waterline query.
Should look like:

```
User.find().where({

    score: { '>': req.params.score},
    status: 'user'
    OR
    status: 'admin'


}).exec(function(err, data){
    ...
});
```

So we have 2 conditions:

1) Score > specific number

And
2) status = user

OR

1) Status = admin.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There was an [issue](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-criteria/commit/d1df6192ae1133f7689b3ab1b1e01f9aa3759494) with the development database used by sails (waterline-criteria).  The issue was the way strings and integers were handled in sails-disk.  In the query criteria below, theScore, was being treated as a string.  This has been resolved, so you just need to update sails-disk.  You can do this by using `npm install sails-disk --force --save`.  After that the example below should work fine.

You can try this **(Updated)**:

```
    foo: function(req, res, next) {

    var theScore = req.param('id') || 0;

    User.find().where({

        or: [{

        score: {
            '>': parseInt(theScore),
        },

        status: 'user'
        },

      {  status: 'admin'}]

    }).exec(function(err, data) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(data);
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks you, but not exactly what I need. So for admin I don't need to check scrope. (So for admin we can have any score, but for user more than param)

Comment: @user2659879, I think my edit should answer and resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
let userResult=await User.find().where({
score: { '>': parseInt(req.params.score)},
or: [{ status: 'user'},{status: 'admin'}]})
```